# How do I round a number in js with negative precision like in Excel round function

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

I am trying to round the value from 8904000 to 8900000 is there any possible way to change this using Math.round.
example  in MS Excel

```
=round(8904000,-5);
ANS: 8900000
```

I tried the code below but Math.round does not take a second argument

```
Math.round(8904000,-5);
ANS: 8904000
```

In short I want to round of the number to the nearest 100,000 number

So that  5300*56*30= 8904000 becomes 8900000

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
function roundDown(number, decimals) {
    decimals = decimals || 0;
    return ( Math.floor( number * Math.pow(10, decimals) ) / Math.pow(10, decimals) );
} 

roundDown(8904000, -5)
```

Comment: Great, this function looks like it does exactly what excel is doing, so round(number,2) and round(number,-5) both works

Answer (score 2):

The common solutions for rounding to a decimal place is:

1. Using `Number.prototype.toFixed()`
2. Multiply the `float` by some `power of 10` in order to leverage `Math.round()`.

Both of these work, except sometimes a decimal of 5 is rounded down instead of up.The rounding problem can be avoided by using numbers represented in exponential notation

Try this

```
function round(value, decimals) {
  return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
}

round(8904000, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.round(value/1000000)*1000000
```

Divide the `value` by the rounding `unit`, hence `1000000`, `Math.round()` the number and `multiply` with the specified `unit`.

Comment: can able to send example for the exact example for the given value in my question

Comment: Replace `value` with what you want to round.